# Add a new widget upon receiving API result

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to build an entirely new widget tree after selecting an option in the `DropdownButton` menu, upon receiving data from a REST API after that selection.

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

> The following assertion was thrown building
>   MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 683.4), devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaleFactor: 1.0, padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
>   viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat:
>   false, accessibleNavigation: falsedisableAnimations:
>   falseinvertColors:  falseboldText: false)):
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed
>   assertion: line 551 pos 12: 'child != null': is not
>   true.

What my code does is essentially to check whether the data is present, which it won't be until the dropdown menu option is selected. Initially when there is no data, the `ListView` in the `Scaffold` holds simply an empty container below the dropdown menu but when the item is selected, data should be retrieved and the whole widget tree rebuilt, resulting in a `ListView.separated` within the enclosing `ListView` instead of the empty container.

The issue seems to lie in the `setState()` method of `onChanged` in `DropdownButton` after some preliminary debugging but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Do note also that the items in the dropdown menu is populated from the API but that is separate from the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The relevant code is as follows:

```
class _TodosByTagsHomePageState extends State<TodosByTagsHomePage> {
  Tag selectedTag;

  Future<List<Tag>> _tagsList;
  List _todoList = new List<Todo>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tagsList = fetchTags();
    super.initState();
  }

  final Logger log = new Logger('TodosByTags');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Second Screen"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FutureBuilder<List<Tag>>(
                  future: _tagsList,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return DropdownButton<Tag>(
                        value: selectedTag,
                        items: snapshot.data.map((value) {
                          return new DropdownMenuItem<Tag>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value.tagName),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        hint: Text("Select tag"),
                        onChanged: (Tag chosenTag) {
                          setState(() {
                            log.info("In set state");
                            selectedTag = chosenTag;
                            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                                content: Text(selectedTag.tagName)));
                          });
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }

                    return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
                  }),
              createSimpleWidget(),
            ])
    );
  }

  Widget createSimpleWidget() {
    if (selectedTag == null) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList(selectedTag.tagName);
    }
  }

  FutureBuilder<List<Todo>> retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList(String tagName) {
    return new FutureBuilder<List<Todo>>(
        future: fetchSelectedTodos(tagName),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.hasData);
            _todoList = snapshot.data;
            return createSelectedTodoListViewWidget(_todoList);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
        });
  }

  createSelectedTodoListViewWidget(List<Todo> todoList) {
    final _BIGGER_FONT = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);

    Widget _buildTodoList() {
      return ListView.separated(
          physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: todoList == null ? 0 : todoList.length,
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32.0, 32.0, 32.0, 0.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(todoList[i].getTaskName(), style: _BIGGER_FONT),
            );
          });
    }

    return _buildTodoList();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I'll start by saying something I noticed about your code: 
You're using ListView somewhat incorrectly. While It's true that ListView can contain whatever number and types of elements and arrange them in a linear way, it *should* contain only widgets of the same type like Contacts or Todos. 
As list view is still a list, like in many programming language, it will take only one type within it, by design, like string or int. 
I'd recommend trying the [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget with a combination of the [Flexible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) and [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widgets.

Regarding your problem, I think it lies in the `createSimpleWidget` function. When `selectedTag` is not null, you're not returning the `retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList` function's return value, so nothing will be returned at all, thus, asserting the child to null. To avoid these things in the future (and also to keep only one return statement in a function), I recommend doing this:

```
Widget createSimpleWidget() {
  return (selectedTag == null) 
     ? Container() 
     : retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList(selectedTag.tagName);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you too on the advice on ListView. Just a question, which might be rather rudimentary, but since I am already returning inside `retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList()` method, why do I have to state an additional return in `createSimpleWidget()`?

Comment: `retrieveSelectedTodoAndCreateList` returns a value to `createSimpleWidget`, but `createSimpleWidget` doesn't return the value to the original function that called it, the builder.